# Mouse pointer jumps around screen by itself

Tags: windows, virus, malware, asus-laptop, cursor

Today, the cursor on my computer (ASUS Zenbook UX331U, windows 10) suddenly started jumping around randomly by itself. Video: https://youtu.be/O2UEBpdsUXQ
Note that the circles are taps (touchscreen laptop). Maybe that's a clue, not sure.

I tried restarting my computer, which didn't do anything. I scanned my computer using Malwarebytes and Avira, and they didn't find anything. Finally, I reset my computer and made a new account from scratch, but the issue still won't go away. I'm not sure what else there is to do at this point; I wanted to enter safe mode but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: this problem even occurs in the BIOS

Comment: Are you using an external mouse or a built in track pad?  If built in, can you try a USB mouse and see if it still happens?  If it does can you disable built in while using mouse and check again?  This sounds like a hardware problem with the symptoms you’ve described so far.  Did it get wet or dropped?

Comment: I've tried both, but the cursor jumps around regardless of what's plugged in.

Comment: Plugging in an external mouse doesn't unplug your trackpad. Since the issue here is unwanted input, rather than a lack of input, plugging in another pointing device won't tell us much. I also imagine it would be hard to use an external mouse or even keyboard shortcuts to navigate and disable the trackpad in software, given all the spurious "clicks". Your best bet might be to see if their is a bios option to disable the trackpad. And hope your bios doesn't support mouse input.

Comment: It was actually the touchscreen that was the problem, and I disabled it through device manager

Comment: It has a touch screen? That was my first guess but when i researched that model nothing i read said anything about it. None the less... glad you got it under control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Are you able to disable the built in device?  Also, is this a touchscreen device? I've had this happen to me in the past and it was because the touchscreen was dirty.  Carefully but thoroughly clean the touchscreen.  If that doesn't help, and if possible, remove the battery from the device while it's unplugged and then hold the power button for about 10 seconds (with no AC and no battery).  What this does is drains any residual current left in the circuitry of the system.  In the industry it's known as "draining the flea power".

If it's not the touchscreen and disabling the built-in device fixes it, then it might be a dirty track pad or loose connection between trackpad and motherboard.  If that's the case disassembly would be required to re-seat the connection, or warranty repair if it's under warranty.

Comment: I cleaned the touchscreen, with no change. Disabling the trackpad seemed to work for a bit, but then I restarted (checked that it was still disabled) and the problem came back.

Comment: Actually, I just disabled the touchscreen and it seems to have fixed the problem. I'll test it some more and update.

Comment: Ok.  It may also be a hardware problem with the touchscreen itself or with it's connection to the motherboard.  I don't know what your technical proficiency is but if it's still under warranty you may consider calling Asus support before doing any disassembly for hardware troubleshooting.  If it's not under warranty or you feel confident in your ability you might try reseating the touchscreen connection cables, or replacing the touchscreen if that doesn't fix it.  I don't know how much effort you want to put into this but you can frequently find spare/replacement parts online, especially ebay.

Answer (score 0):

After month's of having an erratic pointer problem it has finally stopped. Found two drivers listed for the pointer. Switched to the one not highlighted and no more problems.

Control Panel> Hardware and Sound
Devices and Printers> Device Manager
Mice and Other Pointing Devices> HID compliant mouse
Driver> Driver details
OK

Switched driver to:   C\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\mouclass.sys

I think this was the old driver, but Win10 updates changed it.